# TypeError: OWM.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'language'

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyowm

```
import pyowm
import telebot

owm = pyowm.OWM('нет', language = "ru")
bot = telebot.TeleBot("нет", parse_mode=None)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    observation = owm.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.get_weather()
temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']
answer = 'В городе' + message.text + 'сейчас' + w.get_detailed_status() + "\n"
answer += 'Температура:' + str(temp)
if temp < -10:
    answer +='Сейчас очень холодно. Одевайся потеплее.'
elif temp < 0:
    answer += 'На улице холодно. Надевай куртку.'
elif temp < 10:
    answer += 'На улице прохладно, одень осеннюю куртку'
elif temp < 20:
    answer += 'На улице достаточно тепло'
elif temp < 30:
    answer += 'На улице очень жарко!'
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
bot.poilling(none_stop = True)
```

OWM = ('нет', language = "ru")
TypeError: OWM.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'language'

Честно скажу, не мой код, учился по видеоуроку. Пытаюсь запустить код и python не может понять pyowm. Подскажите что делать.

Comment: не надо публиковать ваш api key

Comment: Судя по сообщению ошибки, в методе `__init__` класса `pyowm.OWM` нет аргумента `language`.

Comment: Поиск пробовали? Тут 100500+ ответов на эту тему. Там версия когда-то поменялась, сменились методы работы с библиотекой и половина уроков и примеров кода перестали быть актуальными. Или даже 90%. Так что смотрите какая у вас версия и смотрите документацию к этой версии. Ну и ответы тут, которых ну очень много. Да и вообще помечу лучше дубликатом.

Answer (score 0):

А в доках пишут, по умолчанию язык en, но его можно поменять:

```
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config
config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'fr'  # your language here, eg. French
owm = OWM('your-api-key', config_dict)
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place('Paris, FR')
observation.weather.detailed_status  # Nuageux
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но при исползовнии комнды, которую ты прислал он ругается на config_dict. NameError: name 'config_dict' is not defined

Comment: Да его нужно определить from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'